# To set somebody up, meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is the context: I'm translating a movie and the plot is about two young friends, one of whom is going to move abroad to study after attending an english class. The two girls had an argument and to make up one of them decides to arrange a "lunch date" for her friend with the english teacher, so that the latter manages to get a discount on an english class from the teacher (yeah you read right). After the date the two friends meet each other and they have the following conversation:

- Girl A: Happy now?
- Girl B: He will give me a discount for his class.
- Girl A: But you don't plan to go anywhere, why study English?
- Girl B: To become his wife.
- Girl A: Slut.

[music plays here]

- Girl A: It's beautiful. Whose song?
- Girl B: I wrote it myself.
- Girl A: Really?
- Girl B: I wrote it for you. **Just because you set me up**, doesn't
  mean I'm still not mad at you.

What does "set somebody up" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You set me up = You arranged the date for me

> **set someone up**
>   1.1 *informal* Arrange a meeting between one person and another, with the aim of encouraging a romantic relationship between them.
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/set)